# Filtering an array: how to order the filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

There are 2 components:

1. a filter component that sets the state
2. an output component that renders items based on the filters

There are 2 arrays:

1. an array of all items
2. an array of the selected filtered options.

```js
    let itemsFiltered;
    if (this.state.continent !== "") { itemsFiltered = items.filter( (item) => item.continent == this.state.continent ); }
    if (this.state.country !== "") { itemsFiltered = items.filter( (item) => item.country == this.state.country ); }
    if (this.state.region !== "") { itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.region == this.state.region); }
    if (this.state.activity !== "") { itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.activity == this.state.activity); }
    if (this.state.skill !== "") { itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.skill == this.state.skill); }
```

PROBLEM: it does not work for skill and region. for skill it works if it is selected first, but not if other selections have already been made. For regions it simply doesn't apply the filters at all. Hence it simply shows all items independent of the filter set. It works for all the other filters and combinations of them.

this is what the data looks like (dummy):

```
{
    title: "Item 1",
    description: "Description of the item",
    image: imageItem1,
    continent: "europe",
    country: "portugal",
    region: "norte",
    activity: "kite",
    skill: "proLocal",
},
```

How would you write this to make it work? Should the filters be ordered differently or is there another approach I'm missing?

Extension (code to comments below): Trying to iterate thru the filters fails because you cannot iterate thru the state object:

```
    let itemsFiltered = items.slice();
    const filtersSet = ["continent", "country", "region", "activity", "skill"]
    for (let i = 0; i < filtersSet.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.filtersSet[i] !== "") {itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter( item => item.filtersSet[i] == this.state.filtersSet[i] );}
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you have to pass the filtered items from before to the next filter, like so: `let itemsFiltered = items; if(...) itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Doesn't seem like filtering by more than any single filter should work as each filter operation completely overwrites any previous filtering results.

```
let itemsFiltered;
if (this.state.continent !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = items.filter(
    (item) => item.continent == this.state.continent
  );
}
if (this.state.country !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.country == this.state.country);
}
if (this.state.region !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.region == this.state.region);
}
if (this.state.activity !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.activity == this.state.activity);
}
if (this.state.skill !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => item.skill == this.state.skill);
}
```

## Solution

You can filter each subsequent filter from the result of the previous filter operation.

```
let itemsFiltered = items.slice();
if (this.state.continent !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter(item => item.continent === this.state.continent);
}
if (this.state.country !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter(item => item.country === this.state.country);
}
if (this.state.region !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter(item => item.region === this.state.region);
}
if (this.state.activity !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter(item => item.activity === this.state.activity);
}
if (this.state.skill !== "") {
  itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter(item => item.skill == this.state.skill);
}
```

or to save a lot of array iterations do it all in a single filter function.

```
const itemsFiltered = items.filter((item) => {
  if (this.state.continent) return item.continent === this.state.continent;
  if (this.state.country) return item.country === this.state.country;
  if (this.state.region) return item.region === this.state.region;
  if (this.state.activity) return item.activity === this.state.activity;
  if (this.state.skill) return item.skill === this.state.skill;
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thx, of course, that makes absolute sense. Your first solution works. 

The second solution ("in a single filter function") didn't work. Alternatively, I tried with a for loop, but that doesn't work either. It doesn't allow iterating thru the state object as so: 
    let itemsFiltered = items.slice();
    const filtersSet = ["continent", "country", "region", "activity", "skill"]
    for (let i = 0; i < filtersSet.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.filtersSet[i] !== "") {itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.filter( item => item.filtersSet[i] == this.state.filtersSet[i] );}
    }